# Check null in ternary operation

Tags: dart, flutter

I wanna put a default value on a textfield if _contact is not null. To do this

```
new TextField(
    decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"), 
    maxLines: 1,
    controller: new TextEditingController(text: (_contact != null) ? _contact.email: ""))
```

Is there a better way to do that? E.g: Javascript would be something like: `text: _contact ? _contact.email : ""`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Dart comes with `?.` and `??` operator for null check.

You can do the following :

```
var result = _contact?.email ?? ""
```

---

You can also do

```
if (t?.creationDate?.millisecond != null) {
   ...
}
```

Which in JS is equal to :

```
if (t && t.creationDate && t.creationDate.millisecond) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Notice that this is actually different from the behavior in the original post - this `??` covers the case where `_contact` is not null but `_contact.email` is. The original example would evaluate to `null` in that case, so this code is probably *better* that what was asked for.

Comment: For additional context, `??` is outlined in [null aware operators](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators), and `?.` is outlined in [Conditional property access](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#conditional-property-access)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes null is also converted into a string. So you can check in 2 ways
examples(s)

```
widget.cprice != 'null' - with string    
widget.cprice != null  - with pure null value
```