# Flutter: JSON Parsing data is null

Tags: flutter

When I try to display the parsed JSON data in ListView, I am receiving this error:

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 213 pos 15: 'data != null': is not true.
```

I checked the parsed data, and some fields are null. What is the proper way to check if the data is null and instead display string "Empty" ?

```
Results getShipment(int index) {
    return new Results(
      cargoTrackerCode: data[index]["cargoTrackerCode"]
     )
}

new Padding(                        
    child: new Text(widget.results.customerName,
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18.0,
          color: Colors.white,
        )
    ),
),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check null in ternary operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775261/check-null-in-ternary-operation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator to do an inline if-else sort of statement.

`data == null ? 'Empty' : data[index]["cargoTrackerCode"]`

Comment: Great solution, although it could be slight more easier: `data[index]["cargoTrackerCode"] ?? 'Empty'`

Comment: @JohanWalhout that's not true. If data is null, that would throw an exception.